# Can I avoid/minimize gas fees by running my own Ethereum node?

Tags: gas

Gas costs for even a simple contract deployment on Ethereum mainnet are astronomical. If I spin up my own node and connect directly to it can I deploy on that node and avoid/minimize the gas fees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you won't. If you were to spin up your own [miner](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/59220/what-is-the-difference-between-a-miner-and-a-full-node) you could wait to mine your own transaction. However given the current hash rate of Ethereum you would be very unlikely to find the next hash with just a consumer-grade machine. Not impossible, but would certainly take a while. Having a full node will possibly speed up propagation as you aren't competing with everyone else hitting a public endpoint.

You can think of the difference between a miner and a node, is that nodes will talk to each other about the current state of the blockchain, but miners will actually *change* the state of the blockchain, which other nodes then update each other on. This is an oversimplification, but I think it should do for the question you're asking.